# loop using grep and adding to file

Tags: linux, bash, grep, netstat

I am trying to loop a netstat and grep the results by some values, and then if they match- add them to a file, but it doesnt do a grep, but just adds the whole file:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
  sudo netstat -ano -p | grep x | grep y >> netstat.txt
  sleep 0.05
done
```

What am I doing wrong?
thanks.

Comment: What do you mean, that it "_just adds the whole file_"? Is it possible that `x` and `y` are in every sinlge line? What are the real values for `x` and `y`?

Comment: No, they are not.
It's an IP and a port, that does not appear on every line.

Comment: I'm sorry, but no-one is really going to be able to help you further unless you can contrive an example that we can see. The only reason that the whole file output from `netstat` would be added is because both `grep` commands match something on every line - or your real code doesn't match what you've written here

Comment: Have you applied standard debugging techniques and broken the command turn into parts? Test visually what `sudo netstat -ano -p` produces. Then check  `sudo netstat -ano -p | grep x`, etc.

Comment: Incidentally that loop will produce 20 authentication warning lines in the logs each second. If it runs for any length of time you may end up filling your `/var/log` disk. You should consider removing the `sudo` from inside the loop and having the entire script (or at least the loop) run from a single invocation

Comment: The X and Y are application and ip:port. This does not match all the lines. I I use this netstat and add it to a file, and then after that- use grep manually, it extracts what I need.
But when I put it into a loop and put in a file after the grep- the result is just the whole output of netstat added to the file.

Comment: What is the "true" condition?  That grep x | grep y return a result?

Comment: While true is an never ending loop, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
function append {
while read -r line ; do
echo "$line" >> netstat.txt
sleep 10
append
done <<< $myvar
 }

myvar=$(sudo netstat -ano -p | grep x | grep y)
append
```

The above will return results like this:

tcp        0      0 192.168.1.21:40982      13.83.65.43:443         ESTABLISHED 4220/skypeforlinux   keepalive (26.46/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.21:40982      13.83.65.43:443         ESTABLISHED 4220/skypeforlinux   keepalive (26.46/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.21:40982      13.83.65.43:443         ESTABLISHED 4220/skypeforlinux   keepalive (26.46/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.21:40982      13.83.65.43:443         ESTABLISHED 4220/skypeforlinux   keepalive (26.46/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.21:40982      13.83.65.43:443         ESTABLISHED 4220/skypeforlinux   keepalive (26.46/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.21:40982      13.83.65.43:443         ESTABLISHED 4220/skypeforlinux   keepalive (26.46/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.21:40982      13.83.65.43:443         ESTABLISHED 4220/skypeforlinux   keepalive (26.46/0/0)